# Routing to a pair of active redundant openvpn tunnels so that periodically the 'main tunnel' can be switched over for all new connections

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, openvpn

I have a network the following basic architecture:
  1) clients connect via openvpn, coming in on a single subnet (10.10.10.0/24)
  2) If the client's ultimate destination is the Internet, there are a pair of openvpn client->server tunnels utilizing separate network paths.  Both openvpn clients reside on the inbound machine from (1) and both servers reside on a machine to send traffic out to the internet.  This machine uses a MASQUERADE rule to give the source a public IP address.

[ascii-art diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onLFe.png)

All traffic hits the exit retaining it's 10.10.10.0/24 address.  I can periodically switch traffic heading to either tun1 or tun2 by replacing a custom routing table (ip rule add from 10.10.10.0/24 table tun1 (or tun2).

The purpose of this is to, once it is switched to tun2, allow all traffic to finish on tun1 then have tun1 restart.  The restart allows some internal routing for the tunnel to be altered for security purposes.

Am I not right in assuming that since the traffic gets to the exit with the same src/dst IPs regardless of tunnel that it shouldn't matter if the tunnel used changes?  Yes during the transition packets could possibly arrive out-of-sequence, but the worst-case there would be a few retransmissions which is acceptable.

The current problem I am having is with the MASQUERADE iptable rule on the exit:
iptables -t nat POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

Rule is there and works properly on tun1. However it appears to be ignored on tun2.  I can't figure out why it won't fire for the second tunnel.  Since it's POSTROUTING the inbound device should be irrelevant, right?

Comment: Is it possible you already have another egress rule (in the main table) blocking traffic from 10.10.10.0/24 from  the Internet?

Comment: The 10.10.10.0 traffic comes in from a tunnel so that address isn't seen outside the server.  And it wouldn't make sense from an egress standpoint, since traffic from tun1 has the same src IP so would have the same problem with an egress rule.